# Sort ArrayList of custom objects by String member

Tags: c#, sorting, arraylist

I'm having a issue sorting an **arraylist** of custom objects by a **string** field.
This is the code I'm trying to do:

```
arrRegion.Sort(delegate(Portal.Entidad.Region x, Portal.Entidad.Region y)
                           {
                               return x.RegNombre.CompareTo(y.RegNombre);
                           });
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Argument type 'anonymous method' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Collection.IComparer'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you should use the extension methods provided in System.Linq namespace:

```
using System.Linq;
//...

// if you might have objects of other types, OfType<> will
// - filter elements that are not of the given type
// - return an enumeration of the elements already cast to the right type
arrRegion.OfType<Portal.Entidad.Region>().OrderBy(r => r.RegNombre);

// if there is only a single type in your ArrayList, use Cast<>
// to return an enumeration of the elements already cast to the right type
arrRegion.Cast<Portal.Entidad.Region>().OrderBy(r => r.RegNombre);
```

If you have control over the original ArrayList and you can change its type to a typed list like this `List<Portal.Entidad.Region>`, I would suggest you do it. Then you would not need to cast everything afterward and can sort like this:

```
var orderedRegions = arrRegion.OrderBy(r => r.RegNombre);
```

Comment: I just noticed I had used a `OfType<>()` instead of a `Cast<>()`. I updated my example with comments.

Comment: Quick addition, if you wan't to sort in the other direction:

`var orderedRegions = arrRegion.OrderByDescending(r => r.RegNombre);`

Answer (score 5):

This is because the [Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e743hdt.aspx) method expects an [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.aspx) implementation which cannot be a delegate. For example:

```
public class RegionComparer : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        // TODO: Error handling, etc...
        return ((Region)x).RegNombre.CompareTo(((Region)y).RegNombre);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
arrRegion.Sort(new RegionComparer());
```

P.S. Unless you are still stuck on .NET 1.1 don't use [ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx). Instead use some strongly typed collections.

Answer (score 3):

You need to actually make a class that implements [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.aspx), and provide that.

This can be done with a private class:

```
private class RegNombreComparer: IComparer
{
    int IComparer.Compare( Object xt, Object yt )  
    {
        Portal.Entidad.Region x = (Portal.Entidad.Region) xt;
        Portal.Entidad.Region y = (Portal.Entidad.Region) yt;
        return x.RegNombre.CompareTo(y.RegNombre);
    }
}
```

Then, you do:

```
arrRegion.Sort(new RegNombreComparer());
```

This is one downside to ArrayList, and why using `List<T>` (especially with LINQ) can be advantageous.  It simplifies this, and lets you specify your ordering inline:

```
var results = arrRegion.OrderBy(i => i.RegNombre);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `System.Linq;`.

> ```
> arrRegion.OrderBy(x=>x.RegNombre);
> ```

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot find the method .Order