# Sort ArrayList by Object field value

Tags: c#, sorting, arraylist

So my ArrayList looks like this:

```
        using System.Collections;
        [...]
        //in main:
        Student s01 = new Student
        {
            name = "John",
            surname = "Doa"
        };

        Student s02 = new Student
        {
            name = "John",
            surname = "Doe"
        };

        Student s03 = new Student
        {
            name = "John",
            surname = "Doi"
        };

        Student s04 = new Student
        {
            name = "John",
            surname = "Doo"
        };

        Student s05 = new Student
        {
            name = "John",
            surname = "Dou"
        };

        ArrayList studentsList = new ArrayList();
        studentsList.Add(s03);
        studentsList.Add(s04);
        studentsList.Add(s05);
        studentsList.Add(s01);
        studentsList.Add(s02);
```

Student.cs:

```
class Student : IPerson
{
    public string name;
    public string surname;

    public void Describe()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", name, surname);
    }
```

I'd like to sort my objects in `studentsList` by `surname` and write down both name + surname in `foreach` loop. I know that `studentsList.Sort();` won't work, because it doesn't know in what way it should compare each object to other - 
**and that's where I'm stuck, because I don't really know how to write new comparer that's using value of field of object in arrayList.** I don't even know how to start.

I have to use ArrayList, but I don't have to sort it directly (I can use casting I guess) - in the end it must look like:

```
1. John Doa
2. John Doe
3. John Doi
4. John Doo
5. John Dou
```

Would be great to `Sort()` `studentsList`, because I'd be able to do something like this:

```
int i = 0;
foreach (Student s in studentsList)
{
   i++;
   Console.Write("{0}. ", i);
   s.Describe();
}
```

Comment: why must you use ArrayList?  is this homework?

Comment: Kind of. It's a task for a test and I study for it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202185/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-string-member

Comment: Dumbest test question ever.  `foreach(var student in studentsList.OfType<Student>().OrderBy(x => x.surname).ThenBy(x => x.name))`

Comment: 'ArrayList' does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy' and no extension method 'OrderBy' accepting a first argument of type 'ArrayList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You will also need to add `using System.Linq` for it to work.

Comment: Looks like you missed the `OfType<Student>()` call. But please be aware that `ArrayList` is very rarely used in real code these days - it's been mostly-obsolete since 2005.

Comment: Will, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also define a compareTo method in Student to be able to use studentList.Sort() .
Student class should also extend :IComparable

```
  public int CompareTo(object obj)
  {
        if (obj == null) return 1;
        Student other = obj as Student;
        if (other != null)
        {
            // Compare last names first, then by firstName
            int value = this.lastName.CompareTo(other.lastName);
            if (value == 0)
                value = this.firstName.CompareTo(other.firstName);
            return value;
        }
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a Student");
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, works great - not as simple as linq expression, but .Sort() works ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as following

```
        ArrayList studentsList = new ArrayList();
        studentsList.Add(s03);
        studentsList.Add(s04);
        studentsList.Add(s05);
        studentsList.Add(s01);
        studentsList.Add(s02);

        var studentsList2 = studentsList.Cast<Student>().OrderBy(r => r.surname).ToList();

        int i = 0;
        foreach (Student s in studentsList2)
        {
            i++;
            Console.Write("{0}. ", i);
            s.Describe();
        }
```

Comment: That statement won't achieve anything - you'd need to use the result of the call.

Comment: Works too, but the one that suggested @Will is better, because I don't have to use indirect sorting (using the list).

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var student in studentsList.OfType<Student>().OrderBy(x => x.surname).ThenBy(x => x.name))
        {
            i++;
            Console.Write("{0}. ", i);
            student.Describe();
        }
```

works as it should (thanks to @Will, https://stackoverflow.com/users/1228/will), I didn't realize that linq expression would be that easy. That being said, it's only academic example because ArrayList is mostly obsolete since 2005 (@JonSkeet).